# Troubleshooting, GTX 670 + i7-3820

Tags: boot, cpu, troubleshooting, bsod, gpu

I've tried to figure this out on my own, but so far I've had no luck, so I now turn to the greater forces that be, ie. you guys. I'm sorry if this is in the wrong forum, but I couldn't decide where it'd fit best.

For the past month or so, my CPU overclock of 4810MHz / 130x37 has been rock solid, I've been folding pretty much 24/7. As I wanted to help out with the BOINC milestone on my GPU, I figured why not bump the clocks up a notch. So I followed a guide on the site, and everything went well, I thought. I ended at +70 GPU clock offset and ~450 mem clock offset. I was getting through Heaven on maxed settings and figured I'd let BOINC do the rest of the stability testing.

I then left home for a couple hours, and when I got home my computer was on the endless cycle of sad, as in rebooting, bsod'ing during windows load, rinse and repeat. The bsods I've seen have been an uncorrectable hardware error and machine_check_exception, so I figured it was a problem with my GPU overclock. When I finally managed to boot up in safemode and remove the precision x overclock, it didn't help as much as I'd have liked.

Since then, I haven't been able to stabilise anything but clock speeds on the CPU, and haven't even tried bumping GPU clocks again. I even ended up reinstalling windows just in case precision x had left something behind (I didn't know what else to do), and have basically tried everything I can think of.

What has gone wrong? Have I blown something, or can I fix it?

I've tried to be as clear as I could, but if there's anything else you need to know, ask away.

I have asked this same question on OCN, but patience is not one of my virtues, and the sooner I get either help or answers, the less sanity I'll lose :)

Comment: Is your computer stable at stock speeds?

Comment: I have run 10 passes of IBT at normal, and yeah, it seems to run fine on stock CPU/GPU clocks.

Comment: Okay, that's good. Since Super User is a QA site, I'm not sure it's the best format to find coaching for a stable overclock.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't actually what I was looking for either. I'm trying to figure out why an overclock was stable for a month of 100% usage, only to drop and not being able to maintain any sort of overclock. I mean, if I'd messed with the CPU, I'd understand, but I messed with the GPU :/

Answer (score 0):

I would say - you blew something. You could try to run the system on the HD4000 of the i7 and test. I guess you fried your GTX a bit - and just because it worked for a month it does not give you any gurantees at all!

There are many parts involed, and nearly all of them are sensative to humidity, temperature, voltage and current. By overclocking for that long, some capaciatory might just not do it anymore, or at least not that good. Or there might be other hardware faults.

As said - I would suggest "Replace & Restest". Test with a new GTX, test with the internal HD4000, test with a new i7, test with a new motherboard, test with new RAM. Whatever you can affort, whereever you think it is most likly that a fail happend.